# NullPointerException при попытке открытия карты из NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, google-maps

Добрый день, пытаюсь сделать приложение с GoogleMaps и  `NavigationDrawer`. Когда делаю по шаблонам отдельно либо то, либо другое, то все хорошо. Когда пытаюсь создать проект, где есть оба этих элемента, то при попытке перехода на карту из соответствующего пункта в ND, приложение падает ошибкой:

```
06-28 13:07:26.979  20021-20021/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sample.drawer.fragments.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:19)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Если честно, я не пойму почему вываливается NullPointerException, так как маловато опыта в разработке, и самому разобраться не получилось.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.sample.drawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader;
import com.sample.drawer.utils.Utils;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Drawer.Result drawerResult = null;
    private AccountHeader.Result headerResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Для Activity с боковым меню ставьте эту тему,
        // для Activity без бокового меню ставьте тему AppThemeNonDrawer (она прописана по умолчанию в манифесте кстати)
        // иначе будет "сползать" ActionBar
        // Темы находятся в styles.xml
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDrawer);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // init Drawer & Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        headerResult = Utils.getAccountHeader(MainActivity.this, savedInstanceState);
        drawerResult = Utils.createCommonDrawer(MainActivity.this, toolbar, headerResult);
        drawerResult.setSelectionByIdentifier(1, false); // Set proper selection

        // Покажем drawer автоматически при запуске
        drawerResult.openDrawer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerResult.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Закрываем меню, если оно показано и при этом нажата системная кнопка "Назад"
            drawerResult.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

**Fragment1.java**:

```
package com.sample.drawer.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.sample.drawer.R;

//Фрагмент с картой
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container, false);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**Fragment1.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Манифест**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.drawer"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNonDrawer">


        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.drawer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyApnOzJ4XhFNhRV8zXVCR5BnLjloa8lAK8"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

Не могли бы знающие люди объяснить, что не так?

Comment: [Примеры брал отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/250765/)

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в понимании жизненного цикла активити и фрагментов.

Через активити получить доступ к фрагменту можно лишь после создания фрагмента.

В методе же onCreateView к элементам разметки фрагмента можно получить доступ лишь через View фрагмента.

Вам надо заменить

> map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

на что-то типа

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

---

Так же не очень понятно зачем вы фрагмент во фрагмент запихнули... Почему бы сразу не добавлять **SupportMapFragment** без оборачивания его в другой фрагмент?

Comment: на что-то типа

map = ((SupportMapFragment) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap(); попробовал, но он начал ругаться на то, что невозможно преобразовать View в SupportMapFragment. А про оборачивание, не понял если честно, можно по подробнее?

Comment: Про оборачивание. Почему бы вам не использовать сразу **SupportMapFragment**. Т.е. незачем запихивать его в другой фрагмент.

Comment: Боюсь глупым показаться, но я логикой-то понимаю, но вот в коде не могу догнать где у меня это оборачивание, так как совсем недавно андроидом занимаюсь и потому могу тупить на очевидных местах. Не могли бы носом ткнуть, если не трудно?

Comment: У вас в **Fragment1.xml** фрагмент карты. Т.е. внутри одного фрагмента - другой. И вы можете вместо добавления фрагмента с вложенным фрагментом добавлять сразу же тот фрагмент, коий вы фложили в разметку 1-го фрагмента.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую